# Ecommerce tracking using google analytic not worked

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I try to push transaction's history on google analytic.
I formatted all things properly as i know best to my knowledge.
Below is my code to push data is anything wrong in the code.??

```
    function transactionTracking(itemArray, itemPrice) {
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']); // your GA ID
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);            // track the page view
        var transID = document.getElementById('<%=lblTransID.ClientID%>').innerHtml;
        var totalAmmount = document.getElementById('<%=lblCost.ClientID%>').innerHtml;
        var moduleName = document.getElementById('<%=lblModuleName.ClientID%>').innerHtml;

       _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
            "'" + transID + "'",       // transactionID
            'abcd',  // store
            "'" + totalAmmount + "'"
        ]);

       itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);

       for (var a = 0; a <= itemArray.length; a++) {
        _gaq.push(['_addItem',
                  "'" + transID + "'",          // transactionid ID
                  "'" + moduleName + "'",        // SKU/code
                  "'" + itemArray[a] + "'",      // product name
                  "'" + itemPrice[a] + "'",          // unit price
                        '1'              // quantity
        ]);
       }
        _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code. Also which version of google analytics are you using? `ga.send()` or `_gaq.push()`

Comment: this code is write on Thankyou page.
aspx page basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_addTrans` code is missing with `shipping, tax, country, state, city` values check [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackTrans)

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
   '1234',           // transaction ID - required
   'Womens Apparel', // affiliation or store name
   '28.28',          // total - required
   '1.29',           // tax
   '15.00',          // shipping
   'San Jose',       // city
   'California',     // state or province
   'USA'             // country
]);
```

Comment: Yes they may be set to 0 or '' string if not applicable.

Comment: But as i know these fields may not be included this is the link i followed. please take a look.
http://www.sitepoint.com/track-ecommerce-transactions-google-analytics-reports/

the order ID (required)
the store or affiliate name (required, but can be an empty string)
the total amount (required)
the tax amount
the shipping charge
the buyer’s city
the buyer’s state, county or province
the buyer’s country

Comment: It says:
    2. Add transaction details
The next code block provides information about the transaction. **It must include the following data in this order:**

    the order ID (required)
    the store or affiliate name (required, but can be an empty string)
    the total amount (required)
    the tax amount
    the shipping charge
    the buyer’s city
    the buyer’s state, county or province
    the buyer’s country

Note that numeric amounts must be specified in JavaScript notation, i.e. no thousand separators and a period (.) for the decimal point.

Comment: By the way thanks for quick Reply @Suketu.
i try as you suggested to me. set field to 0 that it is not needed in may case.